# Nested Component in Angular 6

Tags: angular

I have a component A(child) which I want to display under component B(parent).
Component "A"

```
<div [formGroup]="dbForm">
    <div class="form-group">
      <label class="form-label" for="dbServerID">Exposure Server</label>
      <div>
        <select formControlName="dbServer" class="form-control custom-select" id="dbServerId">
          <option *ngFor="let ds of databaseServers" [ngValue]="ds">
            {{ds.databaseServerName}}
          </option>
        </select>   
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Typescript page of control "A"

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-database-server',
  templateUrl: './database-server.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./database-server.component.css']
})
export class DatabaseServerComponent implements OnInit {
  dbForm: FormGroup;

  constructor(private fb: FormBuilder) {
    this.createForm();
  }
  createForm() {
    this.dbForm = this.fb.group({
      dbServer: ['', Validators.required ]
    });
  }
```

Html page of Component "B"

```
<form [formGroup]="newPfForm">
  <div class="form-group">
    <label class="form-label">Name</label>
    <input class="form-control" type="text" formControlName="name" />
  </div>
  <div>
    <app-database-server ></app-database-server>
  </div>
</form>
<p>Form value: {{ newPfForm.value | json }}</p>
```

Typescript of Component "B"

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-new-portfolio',
  templateUrl: './new-portfolio.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./new-portfolio.component.css']
})
export class NewPortfolioComponent implements OnInit {
  newPfForm: FormGroup;

  constructor(private fb: FormBuilder) {
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.newPfForm = this.fb.group({
        name: ['', [Validators.required, Validators.maxLength(10)]],
        dbForm: this.fb.group({
          dbServer: ['', Validators.required],
        })
    });
}
```

Now when I enter anything in the textbox of parent component it's visible in From value but if I select drop-down of child component, form value is not updating. Even I have spent 2 hrs but I am not able to find my mistake.
[screen shot of screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xW4NB.png)

Comment: if you share your code in stackbitz.com it will be easy to help

Answer (score 4):

You should be using the same `formGroup` in `parent` as well as `child` component. You can pass the parent `formGroup` as an input to child component.

Before that create `@Input()` property in child component

component A

```
export class DatabaseServerComponent implements OnInit {
  @Input() dbForm : FormGroup;

  constructor(private fb: FormBuilder) {
    this.createForm();
  }
  createForm() {
   // Simply add child control to the form. No need to create form again
   this.dbForm.addControl('dbServer', new FormControl('', Validators.required));
  }
```

Now pass parent form `newPfForm` to child as an input, so that they share the same `form group`

template B (parent)

```
<div>
    <app-database-server [dbForm]="newPfForm"></app-database-server>
</div>
```

Template of component A would remain as it is. No Change.

Comment: You would also need to add new form controls in Component A under a div which has formGroup directive. In continuation to above, html of Component A would look like
<div [formGroup]="dbForm">
....YOUR FORM CONTROL HTML
</div>
Else you will get Error: formControlName must be used with a parent formGroup directive

Comment: @Avij OP's child component (Component A) already has the same structure what you are mentioning here.

Comment: Ooops...Dint notice that. Looked your answer only.

Comment: You may try this `this.dbForm.addControl('dbServer', new FormControl('', Validators.required));`  Updated the answer with that.

Answer (score 1):

In order to sync the values of nested form components, you need to set the `formGroupName` parameter:

https://angular.io/api/forms/FormGroupName

Comment: Can you point me to a live example as I have followed the link but I am not able to make it work in my case?